# IIS settings to connect ASP to separate database server

Tags: iis, networking, asp-classic, distributed

I have a simple ASP site hosted on the same server as the database.

I am trying to separate these 2 entities and place them on separate servers.
I have setup the IIS settings on the web-server and setup the database on the DB Server.
They both work perfectly individually.

I changed the data-source on IIS config from local to the target DB server db.
Changed other key-parameters and web-config files.

Now, instead of localhost directing to index page, it is re-directing to default page.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Have you used the database server address in your connection string? http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: So can you explain exactly what you do and the expected results - do you go to http://locahost and it gives you the default IIS page?

Comment: @JanuszJasinski. Yes.

Comment: @John. Yes. But it got resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS, click on your site, and look at the "Default Document" section.  You likely need to specify "index.asp" (or whatever) as your default document.